# Find the RGB colour value at a specific percentage of a four stop gradient

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb

**The problem:** 
I have a four stop gradient with colour values at 0%, 33%, 66% and 100%. I want to find out the colour value at any point in this gradient using a percentage.

I think I require some kind of multi stop hue interpolation but was wondering if there was a simple JavaScript way of doing it before I dive in head first and start trying to write my own.

The colour stops I am working with:

```
 //0%
  var stop1 = { r: 25, g: 47, b: 97 };

  //33%
  var stop2 = { r: 75, g: 183, b: 183 };

  //66%
  var stop3 = { r: 237, g: 120, b: 87 };

  //100%
  var stop4 = { r: 209, g: 74, b: 88 };
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so can you display your attempt(s) please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the delta of the interval of the steps and calculate the color with the right ratio.

> How it works.
>
> For example we are looking for the color of 70 % and first, we get the interval of
>
> ```
> [66, 100]
> ```
>
> Then build the ratio by
>
> - the delta of percent and the left interval (`left`)
>
>   ```
>     70 - 66 => 4
>   ```
> - the delta of the right interval and percent (`right`)
>
>   ```
>     100 - 70 => 30
>   ```
> - delta of right and left interval (`delta`)
>
>   ```
>     100 - 66 => 34
>   ```
> - with the above generated ratios, it is possible to calculate the right color inbetween of two colors with the parts.
>
>   ```
>     (color of left interval * right + color of right interval * left) / delta => color
>   ```
>
> Repeat the last step for all colors and return the result.

Working example:

***** denotes given colors, hover shows percent value and RGB value.

```js
function getColor(percent) {
    function getInterval(range) {
        function getRatio(color) {
            return Math.floor((colors[range[0]][color] * right + colors[range[1]][color] * left) / delta);
        }

        var left = percent - range[0],
            right = range[1] - percent,
            delta = range[1] - range[0];

        return { r: getRatio('r'), g: getRatio('g'), b: getRatio('b') };
    }

    return colors[percent] || getInterval(stops.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return a < percent ? [a, aa[i + 1]] : r;
    }, [0, 0]));
}

var stops = [0, 33, 66, 100],
    colors = { 0: { r: 25, g: 47, b: 97 }, 33: { r: 75, g: 183, b: 183 },  66: { r: 237, g: 120, b: 87 }, 100: { r: 209, g: 74, b: 88 } },
    i, color, rgb;

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    color = getColor(i),
    rgb =  ['r', 'g', 'b'].map(function (k) { return color[k]; });
    document.body.innerHTML += '<span style="color: #fff; background-color: rgb(' + rgb + ');" title="' + (colors[i] ? '* ' : '') + i + ' % rgb(' + rgb.join(', ') + ')">' + (colors[i] ? '*&nbsp;' : '&nbsp;&nbsp;') + '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this nice little library for playing about with colours: [chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js)